# How can I compute $\Bbb{P}(M_n=m_n|M_1=m_1,...M_{n-1}=m_{n-1})$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

> Let me define $X_n$ an i.i.d. sequence of random variables which are Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p$. Then for  $M_n=|\{k:1\leq k\leq n, X_k=0\}|$ I need to compute
>
> $$\Bbb{P}(M_n=m_n|M_1=m_1,...M_{n-1}=m_{n-1})$$

But now could maybe someone help me how to compute the probability since I don't see how to work with the cardinality in this case. I think it should be equal to $\Bbb{P}(M_n=m_n|M_{n-1}=m_{n-1})$ but this is only intuitively.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial observation is that $M_n$ counts the number of 'fails' in the $n$ Bernoulli $X_{i}'s$. Thus $M_{n}$ can either equal $m_{n-1}$ or $m_{n-1} + 1$

Let's start with smaller n and examine what we're dealing with. For n = 2,

If $M_2=m_1 + 1$

> $$\Bbb{P}(M_2=m_2|M_1=m_1) = \Bbb{P}({X_2=0}) = 1-p$$

If $M_2=m_1$

> $$\Bbb{P}(M_2=m_2|M_1=m_1) = \Bbb{P}({X_2=1}) = p$$

Can you take it from there

Comment: can you explain me the first paragraph, how do you get there?

Comment: And could you also explain how you got from $\Bbb{P}(M_2=m_2|M_1=m_1)$ to $\Bbb{P}(X_2=0)$ please?

Comment: From the definition: "Let me define $X_n$ an i.i.d. sequence of random variables which are Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p$. Then for  $M_n=|\{k:1\leq k\leq n, X_k=0\}|$" So, let's break it down. $M_n$ is the size of a set. What's in the set exactly? It's all the values of k for which $X_k$ = 0, starting from k =1, up to k = n. Thus, for these n Bernoulli RV's (which can be either 0 or 1), we're counting all the 0's that occur in the first n of them. Thus, we're counting the number of failures (corresponds to an Xi being 0) in the first n.

Comment: With that in mind, let's examine your second question. I said that if $M_2 = m_1 + 1$, then $P(M2=m2|M1=m1)$ =  $P(X2=0)$. This is because given that $M_1 = m_1$, (there are $m_1$ failures in the first 1 Bernoulli RV's), for $M_2$ to be equal to $m_1 + 1$, that means there is 1 more failure now counting the additional failure from $X_2$. That means, we're really seeking the probability that $X_2$ is a failure, which is just (1-p)

Comment: Yes I agree with your computation. I'm not sure about the answer to the Markov chain question, I'm rusty in that area. Maybe someone else can assist

Comment: ah I see perfect thanks!